Unable to find Crystal Reports assemblies in VisualStudio 2019
All the instructions I've seen are wrong or outdated. I'm just trying to include the CrystalReportViewer and ReportDocument classes in my C# app and am unable to install them. I've downloaded a trial version of CrystalReports Viewer. I've download a trial version of Crystal Reports. I've looked in References for the Assemblies. I've looked in NuGet for the assemblies. I've looked in Manage Extensions and found the SAP CR entry, clicked on the download button, and am taken to the overall download page under my account, but of course from there I don't see anything to download for Visual Studio, only to download the 2 packages I've already downloaded.
Can anyone tell me the hopefully simple steps for getting started with my Asp.net C# project? I just need to be able to include the assemblies in order to reference them, and I can't do that. Are they hiding somewhere else from the other downloads I've done, and I have to physically copy them into my project somehow?
